# Ext JS 7.4.0 Modern Wrong variable usage in onChildTrigger of Ext.dataview.NavigationModel

Tags: extjs

I am getting an error in this part of the code in the new sencha 7.4 Modern Version. See my comment in the code.

```
onChildTrigger: function(view, location) {
        var e = location.event,
            isFocusingEvent = (e.type === ((e.pointerType === 'touch') ? 'tap' : 'touchstart'));
        
        // i am getting an error here
        // shouldn't it be e.target.id ?
        if (event.target.id === location.child.id) { 
            this.handleLocationChange(location, {
                event: e
            });
            return;
        }
        
        if (isFocusingEvent) {
            this.handleChildTrigger(view, location);
        } else {
            this.doHandleChildTrigger(view, location);
        }
    },
```

Where can i report Bugs about the sencha framework? The forum said they moved to stackoverflow?

Comment: How about defining `var event = e;` to ensure event exists ;)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you mistyped `event`. This code is working like a charm:

```
    listeners: {
        childtap: function (grid, location) {
            var e = location.event,
            isFocusingEvent = (e.type === ((e.pointerType === 'touch') ? 'tap' : 'touchstart'));

            if (e.target.id === location.child.id) { 
                console.log('handleLocationChange');
                /*
                    this.handleLocationChange(location, {
                        event: e
                    });
                */
                return;
            }
            
            if (isFocusingEvent) {
                console.log('isFocusingEvent');
                // this.handleChildTrigger(view, location);
            } else {
                console.log('isNotFocusingEvent');
                //this.doHandleChildTrigger(view, location);
            }
        }
    },
```